# Identity Framework cant find "User" on masterpage?

Tags: c#, .net, webforms, asp.net-identity

so i followed this tutorial to install and use the Identity Framework in .net.
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project

Everything works fine on the register.aspx and login.aspx page.

I wanted to take this logic from the login page...

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    //do something...
}
```

and put it in the Page_Load of the masterpage (so i can show a Sign In or Sign Out link, depending)

However when i do this, I get an error that reads

> The name 'User' does not exist in the current context

I have the following 'using's in the code behind on the master page, everything here is on the login.aspx page where the 'User' is found.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using SugarSpun_v2;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

i'm a little confused! How do you use the Identity Framework on the masterpage? I'd actually like to integrate the login form on the masterpage itself eventually, so this could be causing me a problem!

Any help appreciated, only just discovered the Indentity Framework, so please be gentle :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closely `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` you refer to, is not part of Asp.Net Identity framework. `User` class is provided as `IPrincipal` which is part of .Net framework. `User.Identity` is implementing `IIdentity` interface which is also part of .Net framework.

What AspNet Identity framework does is puts `ClaimsPrincipal` as `HttpContext.Current.User` which has `ClaimsIdentity` as `IIdentity`.

So all your code that used `HttpContext.Current.User` should work just as fine (worked for me on all project conversions) with the new framework.

As @Kippie answers correctly, `HttpContext.Current.User` should provide you with the logged in user details. As long as there is HTTP request happens.

Comment: Of course, thank you! I knew it would be something simple I just couldn't think of it! Both answered correct, but marked this one as it's more comprehensive :) Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 5):

Try and see if `HttpContext.Current.User` is accessible.